# If you could put multiple smaller ejector pumps in the same space, would it work better than one larger ejector pump?

Tags: aerodynamics, engine, propulsion

I saw somewhere how, for Dyson bladeless fan systems to work for hovering, you'd need an entire grate of ejectors rather than a single ring. However, if you had five ejectors in the same space, each a fifth of the size, or smaller ones at proportionate sizes, would the thrust be enough to achieve lift? Or would the smaller size hamper the thrust output?

And, taking the question further, if each ejector measured only a millimeter across, would that have enough force to lift anything, assuming an equivalent amount of them.

I've tried looking and haven't seen anything that seems to answer this question, but if there are resources I could be pointed toward, or if there are reasonable answers attainable here, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: The thing is, ejector pumps for propulsion in are not in general a good idea: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/53771/could-a-dyson-fan-scale-up-to-be-used-as-a-bladeless-aircraft-engine